# Relationship between correlation and coefficient?

Tags: regression, correlation, statsmodels, least-squares, coefficients

I'm doing some projects and I'm having problem understanding correlation and coefficient correctly. I read multiple articles and I do understand what they mean but I don't understand when it comes to my project.
So for example, I'm analyzing the e-commerce data and the relationship between the 'length of membership' and 'annual amount spent' has a correlation of 0.9, that the more years, the more they spent annually. 
But when I run the ordinary least square using statsmodels, by

```
f = smf.ols('Q("Length of Membership") ~ Q("Annual Amount Spent")', df).fit()
```

And check the summary and find out the coefficient, I get 0.0100, which is a very weak positive relationship between two variable. 
But I don't understand why. I thought the correlation of 0.9 is very strong, that means the are closely related to each other? And that it should have a higher number of coefficient? 
Thank you in advance.....

Comment: The coefficient in the linear model depends on the scale of y and x. For example, if you change "amount spent" from Dollars to 1000Dollar units, then the coefficient will compensate so that we still get the same prediction.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply!! I thought about it might be the issue of scale, but how do I know exactly what amount I need to scale it up?...